# push notifications with NO sound JUST in some situations

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

The app is registered to receive all the 3 kinds of notifications (badge, alert, sound).

I want that push notifications be with NO sound in background JUST IN some situations (in the app user click a button to disable notifications) and to allow the sound for all the other cases.

Do you have some ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From Apple's Remote Notification Guide:

> The aps dictionary can also contain the content-available property.
>   The content-available property with a value of 1 lets the remote
>   notification act as a “silent” notification. When a silent
>   notification arrives, iOS wakes up your app in the background so that
>   you can get new data from your server or do background information
>   processing. Users aren’t told about the new or changed information
>   that results from a silent notification, but they can find out about
>   it the next time they open your app.
>
> To support silent remote notifications, add the remote-notification
>   value to the UIBackgroundModes array in your Info.plist file. To learn
>   more about this array, see UIBackgroundModes in Information Property
>   List Key Reference.

Depending on your model (assuming a system like Parse or something), store the user's preference in the cloud and, when generating your PUSH notifications, decide whether to add this flag or not.